# AWS - Automatic deployment (.NET) to CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have managed to set up a stack using a CloudFormation template for .NET.

I still haven't figured out how to deploy my application to the created stack. Also is there a way to automate the app deployment process?

I have looked at AWS docs but most of them seem to use *cloud-init* which from my understanding is Linux only.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a combination of Userdata to fire off cfn-init (installed as part of the EC2Config scripts) and CloudInit::Metadata stuff to download the source.

[I've written about how to bootstrap a windows instance on AWS using CloudFormation](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/05/bootstrapping-on-aws/)

Basically the flow is as follows

1. get your package onto a downloadable location
2. Update your cloud formation script to include userdata
3. In the Userdata, execute cfn-init
4. In the metadata, provide locations to download source files or zips
5. Execute commands section in the "Commands" section of the metadata

Answer (score 1):

cloud-init is used with windows too.  See the [documentation for bootstrapping Windows stacks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-windows-stacks-bootstrapping.html).